# How to insert in ListView without rebuild in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a chat,  and the problem is that, for example, when there is a video or voice message in the messages, then when insert completely rebuilds everything and fails to watch or listen to the message if the person writes. How to make sure that not everything is rebuilt.

I read that if the key is the same, then this element will not be rebuilt, but I still have it rebuilt. As a key, I give the time of the message.

```dart
PagewiseListView<MessageData>(
      reverse: true,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      cacheExtent: 6500,
      controller: _scrollController,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0, left: 8, right: 8,bottom: getHeight(70)),
      loadingBuilder: (c) =>  LoaderPage()
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      itemBuilder: (c,message,index) => UserMessage(data: message, index: index, toUserID: widget.toUserid, player: mPlayer, key: message.key),
      showRetry: true,
      pageLoadController: pageLoadControllerMessage,
    ),
```

Comment: How do you notice it rebuilds. In other words, what is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: For example, I turn on a voice message and when there is an insert, it just breaks off or when I turn on the video, it starts loading again

Comment: That sounds like something that *should* keep it's state between builds *doesn't*. You cannot stop builds from happening, you should work out why the state is lost between builds.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue as well.

Something that you can do is to assign everything keys. All the widgets that have dynamic values and their parents, etc. Its a little tedious, but definitely worth it.

Another thing that you can do is to break up your widget by extracting parts of your code as individual widgets. When you create new widgets, Flutter will only rebuild the widgets that need rebuilding.

If you continue to have this issue, you can also wrap your widgets in `Builder` Widgets. ***this only works if you are not using setState() to update your state.*** Builder will contain your rebuilds to that specific section of code.

Comment: Keys of the sub-widgets should be different from the main widget? For example the message key and the voice message key that is in it

Comment: Keys should always be unique. Don't use the `UniqueKey()`, that will not help in this situation